# C# PowerShell running non PowerShell scripts

Tags: c#, windows, tcl, powershell-2.0, tee

I am trying to run a tcl script in a powershell so that I can take advantage of some of the powershell features, namely, the tee feature to display the script output in the console and record it to a file in realtime in Windows.

The issue is that I need to call the tcl interpreter (`tclsh`) and provide it the tcl script `"C:\myScript.tcl"` with arguments `--arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2` ...

So the command that I can run in a cmd process is of the form:

```
tclsh "C:\myScript.tcl" --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2
```

I have tried creating a new process and starting the powershell, something like:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("powershell", command);
```

where command is `tclsh "C:\myScript.tcl" --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2`

or

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", command);
```

where command is `/k powershell.exe tclsh "C:\myScript.tcl" --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2`

but those dont work. I either get `tclsh.exe : Parameter -command is specified already.` or it just doesnt run anything.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Ideally, I would like to be able to execute this:

```
tclsh "C:\myScript.tcl" --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2 | tee "C:\myOutFile.txt"
```

and am open to other suggestions. I am aware of windows utilities that can be downloaded and installed to perform the tee function, but I do not want to have to install any third party tools to do this.

Ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: `but those dont work` -- You forgot to tell us what error message you are getting.

Comment: So you're running `cmd`, `powershell` and `tclsh` while all you want is capture the output of `tclsh` and simultaneously write it to a file? At the very least you can get rid of `cmd` here. It's useless and unneeded.

Comment: Update: The errors I get are either: "tclsh.exe : Parameter -command is specified already." or it just doesnt run anything. Question updated.

Comment: @Joey, I originally wrote the app to kick off a new cmd process with a command of "tclsh "C:\myScript.tcl" --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2", which worked great. I figured I could easily start a powershell instance in cmd and run with the desired tee option. I have been looking into just using powershell process to replace cmd process, but im still trying to figure out how to do that correctly.

Comment: That's curious. You are aware that `-command` is not a standard `tclsh.exe` parameter? Supporting it would require something in the script (or a customised executable, but then it really shouldn't be called `tclsh` or we're all going to be confused!)

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
powershell "&{ tclsh --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2 | Tee-Object C:\myoutfile.txt }"
```

should work, apart from that you usually don't have write permissions on `C:\`.